# Content not displayed on mobile

Tags: sxa, presentation, responsive-design

I'm currently designing a website in SXA. I've encountered an issue wherein the contents of a Tab is appearing in Desktop, but not in Mobile. Inspecting the mobile markup, only the texts in the tab is missing, the tab structure itself is there. Also, if you'd notice the change from Tab to Accordion in mobile, we changed the code of the Tab a bit so that the component can change to an Accordion when in mobile.

I would appreciate all the help! Thanks in advance.
[image: Mobile version]
[image: Desktop version]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in **SXA 1.5**

Please contact Sitecore support, they will provide you a hot-fix for this. The code change is required.

For now, without any code changes, you can mitigate this issue by copying presentation details from `Default` to `Mobile`.

[image]

Turns out that this is even better for you as you will be able to switch rendering without custom code

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is great! However, upon doing this, components not in the Mobile layout are not rendered, so I have perform this numerous of times (the client may not like this solution either). is there a way to always render the "Default" layout?

Comment: @Lala Hey. Please contact Sitecore support and mention my name (Alan Płócieniak), they will provide you a hot-fix for this. The code change is required. This is a bug that appeared in **SXA 1.5**

Comment: Thanks! We logged a support ticket for this now. We're in talks with Sitecore at finding a solution for this.